# How to build scrollable side menu using text rotation (or something similar) in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, vstack, hstack, swiftui-scrollview

I want to build a menu like the image bellow where I can scroll between menus. I did try multiple combinations with HStack/VStack in ScrollView and rotation modifier on Text and/or stacks. However, none of my attempts really works as intended.

[image]

## Attempt 1

### Code

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let sections = ["Exclusives", "Apple", "Android", "Videos", "Got a leak ?"].reversed()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
        
            // Header
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color(UIColor.quaternaryLabel))
                .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.2)
        
            // Vertical Menu + Content
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
            
                // Menu using VStack and rotation on Text
                ScrollView(.vertical) {
                    VStack(spacing: 32) {
                        ForEach(sections, id: \.self) { section in
                            Text(section)
                                // padding added on workingdog suggestion.
                                // But steal not producing exactly what I'm looking for. 
                                .padding()
                                .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90), anchor: .center)
                        }
                    }
                }
            
                // Content Placeholder
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color(UIColor.tertiarySystemFill))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .bottom)
        }
    }
}
```

### Result

[image]

## Attempt 2

### Code

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let sections = ["Exclusives", "Apple", "Android", "Videos", "Got a leak ?"].reversed()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
        
            // Header
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color(UIColor.quaternaryLabel))
                .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.2)
        
            // Vertical Menu + Content
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
            
                // Menu using rotation on HStack
                ScrollView(.vertical) {
                    HStack(spacing: 32) {
                        ForEach(sections, id: \.self) { section in
                            Text(section)
                        }
                    }
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90), anchor: .center)
                }
            
                // Content Placeholder
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color(UIColor.tertiarySystemFill))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .bottom)
        }
    }
}
```

### Result

[image]

## Issue

I did try other methods with minor changes derived from these two 2 concepts. But as I understand it, ***the problem comes from using the rotation modifier, which rotate the content, not the view itself (causing unwanted behaviour).***

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Just to clarify, are you just looking for a scrollable set of rotated text views like this picture?

Comment: Yep exactly ! But it has to not cut any word even if some are long (more than the width of the menu).

Comment: I have tried to get this working, but can only get it working when the content is always _longer_ than the height of the screen :/

Comment: I change to "Text(section).padding()" in attempt1 and all seems to work for me. Maybe I do not understand well enough what the problem is.

Comment: I did try you suggestion of adding a padding to Text and it did make it better but some long content does in fact get outside the boundaries of the Text view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did found a good solution using Attempt 2 and rotating the entire Text view using @robniper detailed answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59802487/5541378

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is closer to the picture:

```
struct ContentView: View {
                                                                      // added this space
    let sections = ["Exclusives", "Apple", "Android", "Videos", "Got a leak ?", ""].reversed()
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack { 
            // Menu using HStack 
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack(spacing: 32) {
                ForEach(sections, id: \.self) { section in
                    Text(section)
                        .padding().border(.red)
                }
            }
        }.rotationEffect(.degrees(-90), anchor: .center)
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                // Header
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color(UIColor.quaternaryLabel))
                    .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.2)
                // Vertical Content
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    // Content Placeholder
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color(UIColor.tertiarySystemFill))
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                }
            }
        }.ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .bottom)
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea and in a first look, it seems to work. But by looking closely, you can see that the section string is going out of the Text view's boundaries. Also, if one of the sections string if longer, it overlaps with other strings. But thanks for your idea ! 

Comment: I see the problem now.

Comment: I noticed that if you adjust "VStack(spacing: 132) " then things seems to work with long section strings.

Comment: I've updated the code using a HStack, this seems to work better.

Comment: I did copy and paste your latest code to test it and it doesn't work for me. Even by adjusting the VStack or HStack spacing, the spacing wouldn't be even between Text items (because of the string overlapping). 