# Image in a ZStack is not getting fit after rotation

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to fit an Image into a ZStack after rotating the image. The width and height of the ZStack frame is 300x200. I want to fit the image into that ZStack even after the image is being rotated.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var rotationAngle: Double = 0.0
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Spacer()
            ZStack {
                Image("dummy-img")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: rotationAngle))
                    .padding()
            }
            .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
            .border(.black, width: 2)
            Spacer()
            Button{
                rotationAngle = 90.0
            } label: {
                Text("Rotate Image").padding().background(Color.gray).foregroundColor(Color.white)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Order of modifiers ?

Comment: How can I get it? or What is the preferred order of modifiers?

Comment: It seems that `.rotationEffect()` doesn't update the frame automatically, so you might have to [do it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59802487).

Comment: How can I do it?