# SwiftUI: fix .onHover for overlapping views in custom radial layout

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, onhover

I am currently building an app for macos which will have a view with a varying amount of [trapezoids](https://github.com/hellojoelhuber/swift-trapezoid-shapes) arranged in a [radial layout](https://designcode.io/swiftui-handbook-radial-layout). The individual trapezoids have some information and behaviour attached to them, so they are their own view. These trapezoidViews are created with a `foreach` loop and then rotated with a [custom rotation modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58494193/swiftui-rotationeffect-framing-and-offsetting) that recalculates the bounding box of the view so it more closely matches where the objects in the view are actually drawn after rotation. Roughly:

```swift
@State var displayList = [itemModel]

RadialLayout {
    ForEach(0 ..< displayList.count, id: \.self) { i in
        TrapezoidView(/* ... */)
            .rotated(360/appList.count)*i)
            .onHover { isHovered in
                 // logic to handle onHover                 
            }
            
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that the bounding box which is used for the `.onHover` modifier is significantly bigger than the trapezoids which leads to overlapping bounding boxes (especially when there are many items to display), which in turn leads to buggy hovering behaviour: [image: overlapping bounding boxes on the radial layout]

Do bounding boxes of views in SwiftUI *have* to be a rectangle where each side is parallel to one of the axes, or can they also be rotated? And if they can't, how do I tackle this problem. I thought about whether there is a way to tell SwiftUI to only apply `.onHover` based on the trapezoid shapes themselves, not the whole view (kind of like `.contentShape()` does for touch gestures if I understand that modifier correctly), but I haven't found anything to that end.

Or am I better off just pushing the TrapezoidViews out further from the center, avoiding this problem altogether (but compromising on usability)?

Comment: Did you try using contentShape?