# SwiftUI: Resizing and Rotating Image with Drag Gesture Misbehaves After Rotation

Tags: swift, swiftui, rotation, resize

I am working on a SwiftUI project where I have an image that can be resized by dragging its corners, moved around the screen by dragging, and rotated by 90 degrees upon tapping a button. I have created a ViewModel to handle the logic for resizing, moving, and rotating the image. The UI is structured using a ZStack containing the image and the corners for resizing.

Here's the simplified code for the ResizableRectangle view and the ViewModel:

```
struct ResizableRectangle: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ZStack {
                imageView
                cornersView
            }
            .offset(vm.moveOffset)
            .border(.red)
            .rotated(.degrees(vm.rotationAngle))
            
            Button("Rotate") {
                vm.rotateGesture()
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
        }
    }
    
    var imageView: some View {
        Image(uiImage: .image)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width: vm.imageSize.width, height: vm.imageSize.height)
            .offset(vm.imageOffset)
            .gesture(vm.moveGesture)
    }
    
    var cornersView: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                cornerCircle.gesture(vm.resizeGesture(for: .topLeft))
                Spacer(minLength: 0)
                cornerCircle.gesture(vm.resizeGesture(for: .topRight))
            }
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                cornerCircle.gesture(vm.resizeGesture(for: .bottomLeft))
                Spacer(minLength: 0)
                cornerCircle.gesture(vm.resizeGesture(for: .bottomRight))
            }
        }
        .frame(
            width: vm.borderAreaSize.width + vm.cornerCircleWidth,
            height: vm.borderAreaSize.height + vm.cornerCircleWidth
        )
        .offset(vm.borderAreaOffset)
    }
    
    var cornerCircle: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(.white)
            .frame(width: vm.cornerCircleWidth, height: vm.cornerCircleWidth)
            .shadow(radius: 2)
    }
}
```

```
enum Corner: Equatable {
    case topLeft, topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft
}

@MainActor
final class ViewModel: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    @Published var imageSize: CGSize
    @Published var imageOffset: CGSize
    @Published var borderAreaSize: CGSize
    @Published var borderAreaOffset: CGSize
    @Published var moveOffset: CGSize
    @Published var rotationAngle: Double
    
    let image: UIImage
    var initialImageWidth: CGFloat
    var initialImageHeight: CGFloat
    let cornerCircleWidth = Constants.cornerCircleWidth
    
    struct Constants {
        static let cornerCircleWidth: CGFloat = 30.0
        static let minimumSize: CGFloat = 30.0
    }
    
    struct CornerMultipliers {
        var width: CGFloat
        var height: CGFloat
    }
    
    init() {
        image = .image
        initialImageWidth = 300
        initialImageHeight = image.heightForWidth(initialImageWidth)
        
        let initialImageSize = CGSize(width: initialImageWidth, height: initialImageHeight)
        imageSize = initialImageSize
        imageOffset = CGSize.zero
        borderAreaSize = initialImageSize
        borderAreaOffset = CGSize.zero
        moveOffset = CGSize.zero
        rotationAngle = Double.zero
    }
    
    var moveGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 10)
            .onChanged { value in
                self.moveOffset = CGSize(
                    width: self.moveOffset.width + value.translation.width,
                    height: self.moveOffset.height + value.translation.height
                )
            }
    }
    
    func resizeGesture(for corner: Corner) -> some Gesture {
        let resizeGesture = DragGesture(minimumDistance: 10)
            .onChanged { value in
                self.cornerDragRenderChange(corner: corner, translation: value.translation)
            }
        
        return resizeGesture
    }
    
    func rotateGesture() {
        rotationAngle += 90.0
        if rotationAngle >= 360.0 {
            rotationAngle = 0.0
        }
    }
    
    func canRender(for newBorderWidth: CGFloat, newBorderHeight: CGFloat) -> Bool {
        newBorderWidth >= Constants.minimumSize && newBorderHeight >= Constants.minimumSize
    }
    
    func multipliers(for corner: Corner) -> CornerMultipliers {
        switch corner {
        case .topRight: return CornerMultipliers(width: 1.0, height: -1.0)
        case .bottomRight: return CornerMultipliers(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
        case .topLeft: return CornerMultipliers(width: -1.0, height: -1.0)
        case .bottomLeft: return CornerMultipliers(width: -1.0, height: 1.0)
        }
    }
    
    func cornerDragRenderChange(corner: Corner, translation: CGSize) {
        guard translation.width != 0 || translation.height != 0 else { return }
        
        let aspectRatio = image.size.width / image.size.height
        var newBorderWidth: CGFloat
        
        switch corner {
        case .topLeft, .bottomLeft:
            newBorderWidth = borderAreaSize.width - translation.width
        case .topRight, .bottomRight:
            newBorderWidth = borderAreaSize.width + translation.width
        }
        
        let newBorderHeight = newBorderWidth / CGFloat(aspectRatio)
        guard canRender(for: newBorderWidth, newBorderHeight: newBorderHeight) else { return }
        
        let multipliers = self.multipliers(for: corner)
        let deltaBorderWidth = newBorderWidth - borderAreaSize.width
        let deltaBorderHeight = newBorderHeight - borderAreaSize.height
        let deltaBorderOffset = CGSize(
            width: multipliers.width * deltaBorderWidth / 2.0,
            height: multipliers.height * deltaBorderHeight / 2.0
        )
        let newBorderOffset = CGSize(
            width: borderAreaOffset.width + deltaBorderOffset.width,
            height: borderAreaOffset.height + deltaBorderOffset.height
        )
        
        let newBorderAreaSize = CGSize(width: newBorderWidth, height: newBorderHeight)
        let deltaImageOffset = getDeltaImageOffset(
            newBorderAreaSize: newBorderAreaSize,
            startingBorderSize: borderAreaSize,
            startingBorderOffset: borderAreaOffset,
            startingImageOffset: imageOffset
        )
        
        borderAreaSize = newBorderAreaSize
        borderAreaOffset = newBorderOffset
        imageSize = CGSize(width: newBorderWidth, height: newBorderHeight)
        imageOffset = newBorderOffset.add(deltaImageOffset)
    }
    
    func getDeltaImageOffset(
        newBorderAreaSize: CGSize,
        startingBorderSize: CGSize,
        startingBorderOffset: CGSize,
        startingImageOffset: CGSize
    ) -> CGSize {
        let startingImageOffsetInBorderSpace = startingImageOffset.subtract(startingBorderOffset)
        let width = newBorderAreaSize.width/startingBorderSize.width * startingImageOffsetInBorderSpace.width
        let height = newBorderAreaSize.height/startingBorderSize.height * startingImageOffsetInBorderSpace.height
        let newImageOffsetInBorderSpace = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        return newImageOffsetInBorderSpace
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    func heightForWidth(_ width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        width * self.size.height / self.size.width
    }
}

extension CGSize {
    func add(_ size: CGSize)->CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: self.width + size.width, height: self.height + size.height)
    }
    
    func subtract(_ size: CGSize)->CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: self.width - size.width, height: self.height - size.height)
    }
}

private struct SizeKey: PreferenceKey {
    static let defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
    static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

extension View {
    func captureSize(in binding: Binding<CGSize>) -> some View {
        overlay(GeometryReader { proxy in
            Color.clear.preference(key: SizeKey.self, value: proxy.size)
        })
        .onPreferenceChange(SizeKey.self) { size in binding.wrappedValue = size }
    }
    
    func rotated(_ angle: Angle = .degrees(-90), anchor: UnitPoint = .center) -> some View {
        Rotated(self, angle: angle, anchor: anchor)
    }
}

struct Rotated<Rotated: View>: View {
    @State private var size: CGSize = .zero
    var view: Rotated
    var angle: Angle
    var anchor: UnitPoint
    
    init(_ view: Rotated, angle: Angle = .degrees(-90), anchor: UnitPoint = .center) {
        self.view = view
        self.angle = angle
        self.anchor = anchor
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        let newFrame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
            .offsetBy(dx: -size.width/2, dy: -size.height/2)
            .applying(.init(rotationAngle: CGFloat(angle.radians)))
            .integral
        
        return view
            .fixedSize()
            .captureSize(in: $size)
            .rotationEffect(angle, anchor: anchor)
            .frame(width: newFrame.width, height: newFrame.height)
    }
}
```

I have encountered a problem with the rotation and resizing features. If I apply the `.rotated(.degrees(vm.rotationAngle))` modifier directly to the **imageView** and **cornersView** before all offsets, the image rotates around its center, which is the desired behavior. However, the resizing feature then only works properly if the image is not rotated. If the image is rotated by 90/180/270 degrees, the resizing starts behaving weirdly.

I added the `.border(.red)` modifier to **ZStack**, so you can see where the container containing **ImageView** and **cornersView** is located, even though the image has been moved.

[image: ".rotated() modifier applied before ".offset" modifiers"]

On the other hand, if I apply the `.rotated(.degrees(vm.rotationAngle))` modifier to the whole **ZStack** right after `.offset(vm.moveOffset)`, the resizing feature works perfectly fine after rotation. But, the rotation does not work well if the image has been scaled up/down or moved, as it rotates relative to the original center of the image (or the center of the screen) instead of the new center of the image after resizing/moving.

[image: ".rotated() modifier applied after ".offset" modifiers"]

I have also tried implementing a suggestion from [**this thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58494193/swiftui-rotationeffect-framing-and-offsetting) with a custom rotation modifier using a PreferenceKey to capture the size and adjust the frame of the rotated view, but it did not resolve the issue.

I am at a loss on how to proceed to have both the rotation and resizing features work correctly together. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!